# Catch "Could not start audio source" from nexmo client-SDK debug message

Tags: javascript, vonage

How to get the nexmo debug response? i need to use those error message to show as alert to user.

this my sample code that i try to catch after Nexmo debug:

```
new NexmoClient({ debug: true }).login(USER_JWT).then(app => {
  callButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    //
  });
  app.on("member:call", (member, call) => {
    //
  });
  app.on("call:status:changed",(call) => {
    //
  });
}).catch(function(){
  alert('Show alert from those kind of error.')
  console.error;
});
```

[SDK debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RpZO.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that `error` is not being passed into your catch function.

Try this and let me know if it works.

```
new NexmoClient({ debug: true }).login(USER_JWT).then(app => {
  callButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
    //
  });
  app.on("member:call", (member, call) => {
    //
  });
  app.on("call:status:changed",(call) => {
    //
  });
}).catch(function(error){
  alert('Show alert from those kind of error.')
  console.error(error.message);
});
```